# TableView not showing more than 10 rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am making a tableview, when showing 1-10 rows, everything works fine. However, When adding more than 10 rows. It is building, but in the simulator, it only shows 10 rows.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.greekLetters=
    @[@"CHEM 1100",@"CHEM 2100 ",@"CHEM 3415W",@"CHEM 3511",@"CHEM 3521",@"CHEM 4600",@"PHYS 1150",@"PHYS 2150",@"MATH 1201",@"MATH 1206",@"Adv courses",@"CHEM 2700"];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.greekLetters count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *SimpleIdentifier=@"SimpleIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.row==0) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"General Chemistry I";
    if(indexPath.row==1) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"General Chemistry II";
    if(indexPath.row==2) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Analytical Chemistry";
    if(indexPath.row==3) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Organic Chemistry I";
    if(indexPath.row==4) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Organic Chemistry II";
    if(indexPath.row==5) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Physical Chemistry(HP)";
    if(indexPath.row==6) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"General Physics I";
    if(indexPath.row==7) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"General Physics II";
    if(indexPath.row==8) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Calculus I";
    if(indexPath.row==9) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Calculus II";
    if(indexPath.row==10) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"pick 5 creit";
    if(indexPath.row==11) cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Introduction to Inorganic Chemistry";

    return cell;

}

-(NSIndexPath *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return indexPath;

    }
```

Is the problem of my code or the simulator please? Is it because when I put tableview on the stroyboard, something not right there please?

Comment: The YouTube tutorial series that you may have based this on has some very strange things in it :(

Comment: Yeah, I just follow that tutorial. But I don't see any problem in such a simple code. You have any idea please? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your table view is fully in the bounds of the storyboard? Have you set up constraints correctly?

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to check the bounds please? I don't have any constraints.

Comment: Are you creating this in a StoryBoard?

Comment: Yes, I did creating it in a storyboard. Any trick here please?

Comment: Does it look anything like this quick example I just knocked up? https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so-27883313/get/master.zip

Comment: Thanks abizem, your example works. But I don't know the code I learn from youtube doesn't work as it shows.

Comment: Zip your project and send it to me and I'll have a look. abizern (at) gmail.com

Comment: Any quick way to zip my files please? Sorry  I am newbie.

Comment: In Finder, right click on a folder, choose the "Compress..." option - This will create a zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are one of two problems. Either there is a problem with the `UITableViewDataSource` methods (which does not appear to be the case), or the table view, itself, is not the right size.

For this second scenario (where the table view has been put on a view controller's view, but has the wrong size), there are two ways to diagnose this. The old-school technique is to run the program in the debugger, pause execution, and enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the `(lldb)` prompt:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7b7956b0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b795b30>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7b795670>>
   | <UIView: 0x7c943380; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c9434f0>>
   |    | <UITableView: 0x7d064a00; frame = (0 0; 600 600); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c941de0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c93d3f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {600, 528}>
   |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7c942830; frame = (0 0; 600 600); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c942df0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c942b30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {600, 600}>
   |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7c955b50; frame = (0 484; 600 44); text = 'CHEM 2700'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c955ce0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7c955d30; frame = (0 0; 600 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c955f40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c955da0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewLabel: 0x7c955f90; frame = (15 12; 93 20.5); text = 'CHEM 2700'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c956050>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewLabel: 0x7c9562c0; frame = (314.5 12; 270.5 20.5); text = 'Introduction to Inorganic...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c956380>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7c956680; frame = (15 43.5; 585 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7c956700>>
   |    |    |    | ...
```

If you look at the above example, the main `UIView` has a size of 320x480, but the tableview curiously has a size of 600x600. That's not good. They need to be the same size if you want the table view to scroll properly.

The other way to diagnose this in Xcode 6 is to run the app in the debugger and then you can pause the execution and then press the debug view hierarchy button:

[image: debug view hierarchy]

If you do that, you'll see the view hierarchy and if there are any views that are the wrong size, they'll stand out like this:

[image: view hierarchy debugging screen]

In terms of fixing this, the typical solution is to make sure you have all of the constraints for your table view (e.g. here I selected the table view and I'm adding leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints):

[image: add constraints]

Then, when I rerun the app and look at the view hierarchy, everything matches up nicely:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7bc34ee0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bc352f0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7bc32680>>
   | <UIView: 0x7ba387d0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba38940>>
   |    | <UITableView: 0x7d08d400; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ba37260>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba32a80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 528}>
   |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7ba37ca0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ba38260>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba37fa0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 480}>
   |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7ba3f270; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'CHEM 1100'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba3f5a0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7ba3faf0; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ba40400>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba3fcc0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewLabel: 0x7ba40840; frame = (15 12; 93 20.5); text = 'CHEM 1100'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ba40b20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewLabel: 0x7ba44a10; frame = (153.5 12; 151.5 20.5); text = 'General Chemistry I'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ba44ad0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7ba456a0; frame = (15 43.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7ba45840>>
   |    |    |    | ...
```

Comment: He sent me the code, it was a tableview of fixed size so it wasn't resizing for larger phones. Nice explanation of the debug process, though. :)

Comment: Yeah, I only saw your post after I submitted mine, but the problem was pretty evident from his description. It just took me a few minutes to do the screen snapshots, etc. But it looks like we came to similar conclusions.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in such detail. May I ask that in your last figure, did you add 4 constraint by setting 4 "0" please?

Comment: The more important thing is to click on the "i-beams" next to those four zeros. See how they're in red? I also generally uncheck the "constrain to margins" checkbox, which gives me more backward compatibility with earlier iOS versions, though that's up to you. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

Comment: WOW, thanks for telling me to click on the "i-beams". I did check on it. But the problem is still there.  I will update the snapshot in the post.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, you had a fixed size for your table view. Which meant that it was big enough for an iPhone4, but on taller devices, the tableview wasn't resizing, which meant that the tableview didn't fill the screen and you only saw the first 10 rows, although you could scroll to see all the items.

All I did was add the correct layout constraints to your tableview to pin to to fit the view.

As for the YouTube video from which you've taken your base, I saw some of them this afternoon, and although they are enthusiastic, they have some bad practices in them which you don't want to become a habit. Try the free Stanford course that is available on iTunes instead. A bit harder, maybe, but you'll learn a lot more.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Answer (score 1):

The Tableview is tricky to scroll down on in the simulator. Had the same issue myself.  What I did was left-clicked on the Magic mouse and held the click down and then moved the mouse itself "Up" to bring in the rest of my numbers on the Tableview.  Hope that helps